# React native iOS build is taking a long time

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a big issue with react native IOS build. My project(RN 0.57.1) is taking a long time when I start to archive a project.

I am using the following steps:

1) Cleaning the build folder.

2) Edit schema with release everything.

3) Select Generic IOS device and Product > Archive.

It takes 15-20 min for creating a build and after that 15-20 minutes for compile build. I don't know it's a react native issue for IOS builds or I am doing something wrong here.

Please let me know if anyone having the solution to reduce the time to build an IOS build.

Android builds working fine.

Comment: I am upwards of 30 minutes for iOS.  Android takes about 7... :/

Answer (score 13):

Yeah, unfortunately, it indeed takes a lot of time. You just need to put up with it and take a cup of coffee at such times. Or two ;-)

Comment: Nice answer thanks bro...Instead of coffee i am using my time here. LOL

Comment: I have wasted a lot of time + money to but a new Mac and now I have read this. :(

Answer (score 1):

The heavier the project, the more `frameworks` it uses,  the many `module` is used, the longer it takes.  If you want to shorten the build, you have to reduce it.

Comment: I don't think it is depends on framework. Sample example takes same time

Answer (score 0):

1. Use fastlane plugins and write your own scripts to make your life easier.

Here's the docs.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/cross-platform/react-native/

2. Make sure you're disabling flipper for production builds.
   It slows down build process.

Here's the blogpost related to this:

https://medium.com/salt-pepper/reduce-appcenter-ios-build-by-the-time-50-667ac0eef0e4